# Pre-1996 scifi movie with gray-skinned aliens, quoted in "Zoon Part 3 (Wake World)" by Nefilim

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

There is the song "Zoon Part 3" (1996) by Nefilim (singer of Fields of the Nephilim) in the middle of the song is a small reversed sound clip in one channel. It sounds like a scientist's voice from an old movie:

> Between each finger was a fold of skin, and the creature's skin was gray, and though its blood was red, it was totally not like human blood in composition.

I'm assuming it's a movie because other movie clips have been used in various songs. Does anyone recognize this line from a movie?

Comment: Sound like the Deep Ones from Innsmouth.  Might look for a movie based on "The Shadow over Innsmouth."

Comment: @ZeissIkon apparently a short was released in 2015, but that's 20 years too late :)

Comment: Alice, could you please point out the exact timestamp?

Comment: Description might also fit the Old Ones from *At the Mountains of Madness* but I don't recall a movie of that prior to 1996, either.

Comment: Might be helpful to post an intelligible sound clip of the scientist saying those words to see if anyone recognizes the character's voice.  I don't think it's anything from HPL.

Comment: A timestamp would be very useful

Comment: That is a good idea to post the clip, I will see if I can do that, thanks for the input everyone!

Comment: here is the clip, it is lifted from the one channel run backwards and filtered to make it easier to hear. I recommend a good set of headphones for listening. https://voca.ro/dEyZ2T3SHc1

Comment: The timestamp would be 3:05.  There is the clip in the left channel and another clip of a garbled voice in the right.  I haven't been able to figure out what this is in the right channel, it sounds like just babbling, totally indistinguishable, this could be from the same movie,  idk